# Extracting the coordinates of a point of interest from a ListDensityPlot

Tags: plotting, dynamic

How can I extract coordinates from a list density plot.

Example plot of interest:

[image: 1]

I need to place two points on either side of the center white circle and calculate the distance between them. My idea was to use two locators that gives their dynamic coordinates and connect a straight line between them. And calculate the different between them and output it to the user.

How can I do this with?

So far the only thing I figured out is to use a locators as a line to give me dynamic position.

```
Module[{v1 = {0, 0}, v2 = {2, 0}}, 
 Graphics[{Locator[Dynamic[v1]], Line[{Dynamic[v1], Dynamic[v2]}], 
   Locator[Dynamic[v2]]}, PlotRange -> 3, Frame -> True]]
```

Screenshot of output:

[image: 2]

Comment: [related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29441/5478) Q&A

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple `DynamicModule` combined with a `LocatorPane` should give you a first starting point. The line and the distance could be included directly in the `ListDensityPlot` as dynamic `Epilog`

```
DynamicModule[{pt1 = {10., 10.}, pt2 = {30., 30.}}, 
 LocatorPane[Dynamic[{pt1, pt2}], 
  ListDensityPlot[
   Table[x + Sin[3 x + y^2], {x, -3, 3, 0.1}, {y, -3, 3, 0.1}], 
   ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", PlotRangePadding -> None, 
   Epilog :> 
    Dynamic@{White, Dashed, Line[{pt1, pt2}], 
      Text[Style[Norm[pt1 - pt2], 18], Mean[{pt1, pt2}] + {5, 5}]}]
  ]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

By the way. If you want to have the real coordinates in your density plot, you should provide that data as `{{x1,y1,f1}, {x2,y2,f2}, ...}`.

Comment: Congratulations on breaking 30K!

Comment: Though your image says its 60x60 the extra white boundary adds it upto 62.5. Is there any way I can avoid that white extra boundary from the image so that my locators give me exact 60 from one vertex to the other ?

Comment: @abhilashsukumari You can set `PlotRangePadding->0` or `PlotRangePadding->None` to avoid the white space (see also how @belisarius plotted it).

Comment: @abhilashsukumari I edited my answer and added the `PlotRangePadding` option to make it as big as the graphics.

Answer (score 3):

```
dp = DensityPlot[PDF[BinormalDistribution[{35, 23}, {7, 6}, -.7],
                 {x, y}], {x, 0, 50}, {y, 0, 50}, Frame -> False, ImageMargins -> False, 
                 PlotRangePadding -> None, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Show[Rasterize@dp, 
 Graphics[{Red, Thick, Rotate[Circle[#[[1]], #[[2]]], #[[3]]]}] &@(1 /. 
    ComponentMeasurements[Binarize[dp, .99], {"Centroid", "SemiAxes", "Orientation"}])]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
2 (1 /. ComponentMeasurements[Binarize[dp, .999], {"SemiAxes"}]) ((PlotRange /. 
             AbsoluteOptions[dp, PlotRange])[[1, 2]])/(ImageDimensions[bdp][[1]])

(*
  {{28.0864, 12.8444}}
*)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way using Manipulate and two Locators (using the plot from belisarius answer)

```
dp = DensityPlot[PDF[BinormalDistribution[{35, 23}, {7, 6}, -.7], {x, y}], 
    {x, 0, 50}, {y, 0, 50}, Frame -> False, ImageMargins -> False, 
    PlotRangePadding -> None, AspectRatio -> Automatic];
Manipulate[Show[dp, Graphics[{Line[{p1, p2}],  Inset[Norm[p1 - p2]]}]], 
    {{p1, {10, 10}}, Locator}, {{p2, {20, 20}}, Locator}]
```

[image]

Comment: Are you measuring in the same scale of the Density plot?

Comment: @belisarius - using your density plot map, it has the same scale...

Comment: OK, +1 now .. :)