# Locator with Integer value coordinates

Tags: dynamic, locator

I want to get the Pixel value of an image.and here is my code

```
DynamicModule[{p = {50, 50}},
  {Show[img, Graphics[Locator[Dynamic[p]]]], 
                 ImageValue[img, Dynamic[p]]}]
```

and it came up with a warning that p is with a non integer value,
to solve the problem ,I used `Floor` to get an integer value

```
DynamicModule[{p = {50, 50}},
  {Show[img, Graphics[Locator[Dynamic[p]]]], 
                 ImageValue[img,Floor/@Dynamic[p]]}]
```

this time it still doesnt work, with a warning:

```
    ImageValue::imgrng: The specified argument Floor[p$20303] should be a pair of real or      integer numbers or a list of those.
```

My question is ,can I strict the loactor to Integer Domain?or is there any more elegent way to deal with this problem?

Comment: The approach is almost good. However `Dynamic[p]` has `Head` `Dynamic` and some functions are not able to cooperate with it so you have to move `Dynamic` outside. You may also want to take a look at related [locator on a png file](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29443/5478). (*pay attention to the coordinates which are relevant in your case*)

Comment: @Kuba,tks, as you said, I fixed the problem, it works well now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kuda's help is quite useful, it helps me to fix the problem,

The thing is that `Floor[Dynamic[p]]`would not work properly, so ImageValue can't be updated.

So, After moving the `Dynamic`out side the `ImageValue`,it works

```
DynamicModule[{p = {50, 50}},
    {Show[img, Graphics[Locator[Dynamic[p]]]], 
       Dynamic[ImageValue[img, Floor /@ p]]}]
```

[image]